# Is there a cheaper alternative to cinema displays?

Tags: display, hardware-recommendation

Apple displays are great, except for the price.

I'm looking to replace my LG 19" display with a 24".

I can't find any screen that isn't overly widescreen, it's ridiculous ! Wide is good but too wide isn't useful, Apple 24" displays have the screen estate I'm looking for.

Dell used to do nice 24" (2408WFP) but they don't sell them anymore.

Is there any display out there which shares the ratio of Apple's cinema displays but also cheaper ?

Comment: With "overly widescreen", do you mean you are accustomed to 16:10 so 16:9 seems a bit extreme? (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16:10)

Comment: Apple cinema display is expensive because of the usb ports & what not; but I'm sure you can find a similar monitor for cheaper from any leading monitor brand such as Acer etc.

Answer (score 3):

How about Dell U2410. I use one at home and it is a great monitor.

Comment: I was posting exactly this monitor. The great thing is that it's actually an [IPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFT_LCD#In-plane_switching_.28IPS.29) panel, which can display 16.7 million colors, instead of only 65,536 like the way more common and cheap TN panels (like the ones in laptops) that fake the other colors by using [dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithering) (hence the crappy color banding). It's also 16:10.

Comment: It seems to be a really nice screen with loads of inputs and the fact that you can rotate it is great. A bit expensive unfortunatly.

Answer (score 2):

## [Samsung P2770HD](http://www.hdtvreview.com/Samsung-P2770HD-hdtv.html)

27" and a resolution of 1920x1080. However only 16bits per pixel, so color banding is very visible. I recently bought one cheap. Happy about the size. Not too happy about the colors.

The Cinema displays can go up to 2560x1440 and has 24bits per pixel, so this Samsung display can only compete on size and price.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "overly widescreen" - are you looking at these screens in person or on the web? How can you tell they're overly wide?

I'd be far more concerned with display quality than display sizing. The Dell screens I've used in the past have always been terrible at getting the color quality that a macbook pro screen has.

I'm currently using a Samsung 2333HD next to my MBP and it's a serious competitor to the apple display quality, in my opinion. To be fair, it's just under your specs at 23" but it's more than enough extra screen real estate for me and you'll surely be impressed if you're upgrading from a 19".

The newest apple display is 19.35"x25.7"x8.15" (and that's for a 27" screen) whereas the 2333HD is 16.5"x21.8"x8.5" (for 23") so very close to the same depth and 3"/4" less height/width for 4" less screen size. It's the same 16:9 aspect ratio, so you probably won't be disappointed by the width and, again, you definitely won't miss out on quality. Seems like it runs around $200 these days, I got mine for $150 on sale so you could probably search around a bit for a better price.

Comment: Display quality isn't such a problem for me. I do have a 16:10 screen now and not 16:9. Those that I've seen in person are mostly HP screen, they seem overly wide because of their very low height.

Answer (score 0):

DELL U2410 is a good choice and new U2412M which use LED as backlight cost less energy.